# Convert String type to slug type for sanity io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

I am importing data from an external API into my sanity schema and the API contains the slug in the form of a string. I have tried removing the double quotes of the string and making it single quoted but that is still not accepted by sanity as slug type.

So how do I convert it to the slug type?

code I'm currently using:

`const slicedSlug = externalReport.slug.replace(/["]+/g, '');`

Answer (score 2):

The slug is an "object" with `_type: 'slug'`. In case you were trying to add it as a string, try this:

```js
const slug = {
    _type: 'slug',
    current: 'your-slug-without-quotes',
};
```

Personally I would also replace spaces and make all lower caps but it might not be relevant to your situation.

`yourSlug.replace(/["]+/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();`

Comment: Just remove the quotes from the string. will that change the datatype? Also is the above code enough to remove the quotes?

Comment: No, I believe you need the whole thing: `{ _type: 'slug', current: 'your-slug-string-here' }`

Comment: Your code replaces the string, just fine. But I might also do replace whitespace with '-'.

Comment: Yes im doing the `{_type: }`  thing as you have specified and the slug stored in the api already has it in the 'this-is-slug" form. but even after making it single quoted it is still not accepting it :(

Comment: Hmm.. Strange.. Do you have space or special characters? Are you sure all slugs are unique to the dataset? Can you provide an example slug which it rejects?

Comment: ok so an example slug would be 'america-water-trends' which originally in the api was "america-water-trends" and yes all the slugs are unique im sure of that

Comment: Looks good! Afraid I'm not much help to you then. My code set this slug with no errors. If you are stuck on this, provide more code and context. Maybe someone else knows what your problem can be ,'-)

Comment: Thnx for your help! Do u have experience importing external data into sanity schema?

Comment: I export and import quite a lot, both through the Command Line Interface with .ndjson files and with node/js using sanity client library. Thought your case would be an easy one ,'-)

Comment: Oh thats great! Would it be possible for you to help me clear out a few doubts in chat?

Comment: I can try! Never used the chat so might need som tips on getting started..

Comment: I guess you need 100+ reputation to create a chat room. It would be good if someone made one for SANITY so us low-rep people could hatch out a solution and update this post ,'-)